# Applications to design ERD Diagrams for Databases

Tags: linux, erd

I am looking for applications (with preference to Linux based, but can work with windows based too), that allow for ERD design of a database on conceptual level.
This is for assignments I have at class, where they do ERD differently than the programs I have already tried (such as: MySQL Workbench, Oracle SQL Developer, DBDesigner4).

None make ERD in a way where Entities are simple rectangles (with entity name), and attributes of the entity are oval circles connected to that rectangle.
Instead, they all show it in the more formalized way of a table name, and its properties.

Here is an example from the book (Database Management Systems, third Edition from Ramakrishnan Gehrke) of what I mean by an ERD, which the above mentioned applications DON'T do:

https://web.archive.org/web/20141226024652if_/http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/920/20130505111142.jpg

EDIT: I know of one web app to do it called Gliffy that classmates use, but I am specifically looking for Applications since I never liked web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://live.gnome.org/Dia/  allows for what you're after (via plugins/extensions also listed on its website) for some RBMSes.

Comment: Thank you! the arrows are a bit tricky to position however, otherwise it is perfect :)

Comment: However, I cant seem to figure out, how to add relationships to lines such as 1:N, 1:1 etc as here:

Comment: Figured it out: 1:N etc are set on the properties of a Relationship object.